# Making missing manual js & jQuery external instead on inline

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still relatively new to javascript and jQuery. I'm doing a online course that covered the absolute basics before giving out an assignment that involved form validation. For the life of me I can't do it and I've searched for different approaches to it. No matter what I try as soon as I put the javascript in a external file I lose the validation. Or the approaches I try don't cover everything I need them to and as soon as I add in the extras I need it doesn't work.

I've been using Missing Manual's Javascript & jQuery book to help me gain a better understanding of the languages but I'm back at the same issue - as soon as I move the javascript and jQuery to an external file I lose all validation.

I've included the code from the Missing Manual book to help (I know that's somewhat irrelevant but the idea is once I've sussed out how to get the external file working I'm going to apply the same approach to my code so I'm still learning for myself and not getting someone else to do my assignment for me)

tldr; I can't get the javascript/jQuery to an external file without losing the validation entirely

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#signup').validate({
       rules: {
         email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
         },
         password: {
            required: true,
            rangelength:[8,16]
         },
         confirm_password: {equalTo:'#password'},
         spam: "required"
       }, //end rules
       messages: {
          email: {
             required: "Please supply an e-mail address.",
             email: "This is not a valid email address."
           },
          password: {
            required: 'Please type a password',
            rangelength: 'Password must be between 8 and 16 characters long.'
          },
          confirm_password: {
            equalTo: 'The two passwords do not match.'
          }
       },
       errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
           if ( element.is(":radio") || element.is(":checkbox")) {
              error.appendTo( element.parent()); 
            } else {
              error.insertAfter(element);
            } 
        } 

      }); // end validate 
    }); // end ready
```

```css
#signup label.error {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #F00;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 215px;
}
#signup  input.error, #signup select.error  {
  background: #FFA9B8;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
  JAVASCRIPT <span class="amp">&amp;</span> jQUERY: THE&nbsp;MISSING&nbsp;MANUAL
  </header>
  <div class="content">
  <div class="main">
 <h1>Signup</h1>
   <form action="process.html" method="post" name="signup" id="signup">
     <div>
       <label for="name" class="label">Name </label>
       <input name="name" type="text" class="required" id="name" title="Please type your name.">
     </div>
     <div>
       <label for="email" class="label">E-mail Address</label>
       <input name="email" type="text" id="email">
     </div>
     <div>
       <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
       <input name="password" type="password" id="password">
     </div>
     <div>
       <label for="confirm_password" class="label">Confirm Password</label>
       <input name="confirm_password" type="password" id="confirm_password">
     </div>
     <div><span class="label">Hobbies</span>
       <input name="hobby" type="checkbox" id="heliskiing" value="heliskiing" class="required" title="Please check at least 1 hobby.">
       <label for="heliskiing">Heli-skiing</label>
       <input name="hobby" type="checkbox" id="pickle" value="pickle">
       <label for="pickle">Pickle eating</label>
       <input name="hobby" type="checkbox" id="walnut" value="walnut">
       <label for="walnut">Making walnut butter</label>
     </div>
     <div>
       <label for="dob" class="label">Date of birth</label>
       <input name="dob" type="text" id="dob" class="date" title="Please type your date of birth using this format: 01/19/2000">
     </div>
     <div>
        <label for="planet" class="label">Planet of Birth</label>
        <select name="planet" id="planet" class="required" title="Please choose a planet.">
          <option value="">--Please select one--</option>
          <option value="earth">Earth</option>
          <option value="mars">Mars</option>
          <option value="alpha centauri">Alpha Centauri</option>
          <option value="forget about it">You've never heard of it</option>
       </select>
     </div>
     <div>
       <label for="comments" class="label">Comments</label>
       <textarea name="comments" cols="15" rows="5" id="comments">   </textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="labelBlock">Would you like to receive annoying e-mail froM
    US? </div>
     <div class="indent">
       <input  type="radio" name="spam" id="yes" value="yes" class="required" title="Please select an option">
       <label for="yes">Yes</label>
       <input type="radio" name="spam" id="definitely" value="definitely">
       <label for="definitely">Definitely</label>
       <input type="radio" name="spam" id="choice" value="choice">
       <label for="choice">Do I have a choice?</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>JavaScript &amp; jQuery: The Missing Manual, 3rd Edition, by <a href="http://sawmac.com/">David McFarland</a>. Published by <a href="http://oreilly.com/">O'Reilly Media, Inc</a>.</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: So what does it look like when you put it in an external file?  Both the file and how are you included it on the page?

Comment: if you open the dev tools (pressing `F12`), do you see an error in the console?

Comment: At the moment I've just put all the js/jquery into its own file and linked it in. (I'm just trying stuff I'm coming across online coz I'm completely out of my depth) and the error in the console tells me that it can't access the file with the js